# mutate based on filtering dot gives 'Non numeric agr to binary'

Tags: r, dplyr

A dataframe:

```
sub_funnel_data %>% dput
structure(list(funnelstep = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Sessions", 
"Engaged Sessions", "Subscription Funnel - Arrives on Enter Email", 
"Subscription Funnel - Arrives on Payment Details", "Direct to Paid"
), class = "factor"), N = c(92853L, 33107L, 3469L, 3149L, 113L
), Drop = c(NA, 0.356552830818606, 0.104781466155194, 0.907754396079562, 
0.0358844077484916)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Looks like:

```
sub_funnel_data
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  funnelstep                                           N    Drop
* <fct>                                            <int>   <dbl>
1 Sessions                                         92853 NA     
2 Engaged Sessions                                 33107  0.357 
3 Subscription Funnel - Arrives on Enter Email      3469  0.105 
4 Subscription Funnel - Arrives on Payment Details  3149  0.908 
5 Direct to Paid                                     113  0.0359
```

I'd like to mutate a new column 'Rate' that is N / What N is when funnelstep == 'Sessions'.

Tried:

```
sub_funnel_data %>% mutate(Rate = N / (. %>% filter(funnelstep == 'Sessions') %>% pull(N)))
```

Which gave:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Rate`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
ℹ Input `Rate` is `N/(. %>% filter(funnelstep == "Sessions") %>% pull(N))`.
```

How can I mutate where new column 'Rate' is N over the N where funnelstep == 'sessions'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this?

```r
sub_funnel_data %>%
  mutate(Rate = N / N[funnelstep == "Sessions"])
# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#   funnelstep                                           N    Drop    Rate
# * <fct>                                            <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 Sessions                                         92853 NA      1      
# 2 Engaged Sessions                                 33107  0.357  0.357  
# 3 Subscription Funnel - Arrives on Enter Email      3469  0.105  0.0374 
# 4 Subscription Funnel - Arrives on Payment Details  3149  0.908  0.0339 
# 5 Direct to Paid                                     113  0.0359 0.00122
```

In this example, there is only one match so it makes sense ... if it is at all conceivable that you will have either zero `"Sessions"` or more than 1, you should add logic to deal with that. For instance, a no-match scenario errors with:

```r
sub_funnel_data %>%
  mutate(Rate = N / N[funnelstep == "Sessions99"])
# Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Rate`.
# x Input `Rate` can't be recycled to size 5.
# i Input `Rate` is `N/N[funnelstep == "Sessions99"]`.
# i Input `Rate` must be size 5 or 1, not 0.
```

and a multi-match warns and logically-fails with

```r
sub_funnel_data %>%
  mutate(Rate = N / N[grepl("^Subscription", funnelstep)])
# Warning: Problem with `mutate()` input `Rate`.
# i longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
# i Input `Rate` is `N/N[grepl("^Subscription", funnelstep)]`.
# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#   funnelstep                                           N    Drop    Rate
# * <fct>                                            <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 Sessions                                         92853 NA      26.8   
# 2 Engaged Sessions                                 33107  0.357  10.5   
# 3 Subscription Funnel - Arrives on Enter Email      3469  0.105   1     
# 4 Subscription Funnel - Arrives on Payment Details  3149  0.908   1     
# 5 Direct to Paid                                     113  0.0359  0.0326
```

While both of those are obviously contrived, I suggest considering if defensive programming is in order.

For example,

```r
sub_funnel_data %>%
  mutate(Rate = N / (if (sum(funnelstep == "Sessions") == 1L) N[funnelstep == "Sessions"] else NA))
# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#   funnelstep                                           N    Drop    Rate
# * <fct>                                            <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 Sessions                                         92853 NA      1      
# 2 Engaged Sessions                                 33107  0.357  0.357  
# 3 Subscription Funnel - Arrives on Enter Email      3469  0.105  0.0374 
# 4 Subscription Funnel - Arrives on Payment Details  3149  0.908  0.0339 
# 5 Direct to Paid                                     113  0.0359 0.00122
```

A bit wordy, but ...

Comment: This is great thanks! In this particular case there will always be a 'Sessions' row but good to know

Answer (score 1):

We could add a `{}` to block the `.` and then it will work without any error

```
sub_funnel_data %>%
     mutate(Rate = N / ({.} %>%
           filter(funnelstep == 'Sessions') %>% 
           pull(N)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  funnelstep                                           N    Drop    Rate
* <fct>                                            <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Sessions                                         92853 NA      1      
2 Engaged Sessions                                 33107  0.357  0.357  
3 Subscription Funnel - Arrives on Enter Email      3469  0.105  0.0374 
4 Subscription Funnel - Arrives on Payment Details  3149  0.908  0.0339 
5 Direct to Paid                                     113  0.0359 0.00122
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun. I tried that and it failed because I wrapped the entire expression after the `/` in {} and not just the dot. Now I know!